# Getting Error When I Run The Griffon Application

Tags: groovy, griffon

I'm using Ubuntu and i have installed Griffon by taking the steps from this [site](https://gist.github.com/1086306). Even though there is no error in my installation. When i try to run the Griffon app using the command :

```
griffon run-app
```

I'm getting the error as:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "null/bin/java" (in directory "/home/anto/anto/staging"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GriffonScriptRunner.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.callPluginOrGriffonScript(GriffonScriptRunner.java:518)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.executeCommand(GriffonScriptRunner.java:300)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.main(GriffonScriptRunner.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.support.GriffonStarter.rootLoader(GriffonStarter.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.support.GriffonStarter.main(GriffonStarter.java:223)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "null/bin/java" (in directory "/home/anto/anto/staging"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at RunApp$_run_closure2.doCall(RunApp.groovy:100)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:32)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 12 more
```

How to escape from this and run my first Griffon app?

Comment: `null/bin/java` is probably being expanded from `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`.  Is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set properly?

Comment: How do i set that? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk` to your `.bashrc`, substituting your actual JDK path.  Try `readlink /etc/alternatives/javac` if you're not sure where your JDK is installed.

Comment: this works perfect. Please enter this as an answer and I will accept it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null/bin/java` is probably being expanded from `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`.

To properly set your `JAVA_HOME` on an Ubuntu box, add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk` to your `.bashrc`, substituting your actual JDK path. Try `readlink /etc/alternatives/javac` if you're not sure where your JDK is installed.

Comment: Just for the record, as they say [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/), in MacOSX you should `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that ppa package is broken.

** Best to use the standard installation method: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Installing+Griffon .

However, it's possibly just because you need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable, and possibly install the JDK itself? ... approximately:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
sudo echo "export JAVA_HOME=/wherever/java/is/installed" > /etc/profile.d/java.sh
sudo chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/java.sh
. /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

HTH

Comment: I have installed Java properly. Grails running on my Pc

Comment: If set, and you're comfortable setting ENV vars, then try installing GRIFFON normally, according to that link

Comment: ah, I just saw your answer to a comment above. My answer also would have worked! (/etc/profile.d/*.sh is effectively processed at the same as .bashrc , but it works for all users ...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have Java installed/configured properly. Type the following at the command line:

> java -version

You should see output similar to:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

If not, you need to install Java (if it's not already installed), then set a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the directory where Java is installed. You should also add `$JAVA_HOME\bin` to your `$PATH` variable

Comment: I have installed Java properly. Grails running on my Pc

Comment: Did you do the command-line test above? If you're running Grails from an IDE then it will work even if you don't have the environment variables set

Comment: Ya i tried it! And anyhow I use Grails using command-prompt only! I guess the error is somewhere else :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, some ubuntu package upgrades or new installs break (some of) the configured java* alternatives.
When this happens, check and correct them into a shell:

Type 'update-alternatives --config java' and type the [TAB] key twice in order to use the bash completion and see all java* alternatives.

Now, check and correct them one by one if needed:
'update-alternatives --config java'
etc..